# Batch: how to mklink with arguments?

Tags: windows, batch-file, symlink, mklink

How to create a [symlink](/questions/tagged/symlink) in [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) including arguments using [mklink](/questions/tagged/mklink), *(and no [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell))*?

I want to create on `Desktop` a link `OpenVPN` which links to `"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe"`, with argument: `--connect client.ovpn`

So I tried:

1. `cd %homepath%\Desktop && mklink "OpenVPN GUI" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe --connect client.ovpn"`
   FAILED -> symlink created but unable to point to `.exe`.
2. `cd %homepath%\Desktop && mklink "OpenVPN GUI" ""C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect client.ovpn"`
   FAILED -> Obviously syntax error.
3. Trying to use escape character `^` and `\`: `cd %homepath%\Desktop && mklink "OpenVPN GUI" "^"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe^" --connect client.ovpn"`
   FAILED.
4. I tried to set a variable `set patharglink="C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect client.ovpn`, and use it, `mklink "OpenVPN GUI" %patharglink%`
   FAILED.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You need to explain what type of symlink you're trying to create? A symlink cannot include switches/arguments, what you appear to be looking for is a shortcut? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60764621/edit) to clarify.

Comment: A symlink (symbolic link) is a filesystem reparse point that redirects to another file, which is processed at a low level by the filesystem, I/O manager, and object manager in the kernel. What you want is a shell link file (i.e. a .LNK file), which the shell uses at a high level in user mode in order to open a target file, with the option of command line arguments, if the file type supports arguments (e.g. an executable or script).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a complete [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), to create the **shortcut, *not symbolic link***, you require.

```batch-file
;@If Not Exist "%UserProfile%\Desktop\OpenVPN.lnk" (
;   "%__AppDir__%rundll32.exe" advpack.dll,LaunchINFSection "%~0",,1)
;@GoTo :EOF
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
[DefaultInstall]
ProfileItems=AddLnk
[AddLnk]
Name="OpenVPN",8,16
CmdLine=16422,"OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe"," --connect client.ovpn"
InfoTip="Connect OpenVPN using client config file"
WorkingDir=0
```

Just save the above as `OVPNLink.cmd` and double click it!

Comment: Thanks, very interesting this way. Can you explain me well how it works?. But is not useful for me, because I can't add batch commands after this rows

Comment: Of course you can add more commands, @AccaEmme, _(but that's outside of your initial question)_. Each of your commands go between line `2` and line `3`, and must be prefixed with a semicolon too. As for an explanation, unfortunately I have no interest in teaching for free, so at this time I'm afraid you're out of luck. Please do not take offence at my decision.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to create a shortcut (not a symbolic link, as others pointed out) with arguments, mainly through [this thread](https://administrator.de/forum/verkn%C3%BCpfungen-erstellen-72240.html).

The Idea is to call a VB script, because there is an easy implementation for shortcuts:

```batch-file
:: make sure the linkpath exists:
if not exist "%linkpath%" md "%linkpath%"

:: create temporary VBScript ...
echo Set objShell=WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")>%temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs
echo Set objShortcut=objShell.CreateShortcut("%linkpath%\%linkname%.lnk")>>%temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs
echo objShortcut.TargetPath="%progpath%\%progexe%.exe">>%temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs
echo objShortcut.Arguments="%arguments%">>%temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs
echo objShortcut.Description="%description%">>%temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs
echo objShortcut.WorkingDirectory="%progpath%">>%temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs
echo objShortcut.Save>>%temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs

::... run it ...
cscript //nologo %temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs

::... and delete it.
del %temp%\MakeShortCut.vbs
```

So you will want to set the following variables before running these lines:

- `%linkpath%` is the path where the shortcut is created
- `%linkname%` is the name of the shortcut
- `%progpath%` is the path to your executable
- `%progname%` is the name of your executable
- `%arguments%`
- `%description%`

`%temp%` is not to be set, it is an environment variable

note:
***I modified that code a little from the code I am using, as I have a specific use for it in my code, and did not test if I made a typo here. If anyone uses this and it works, please feel free to remove this note***

Comment: You could write the whole .lnk file in batch, but you would have to implement that from scratch